# Calling labels from the table function in R

Tags: r

I am currently using **R** to convert data from an experiment into a high quality dataset. One of the features of my code is to detect repetitions of the experiment and label them accordingly. I have written the following code for this:-

```
DAYREP<-function(a){
  CAPS<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P",
          "Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z")
  if (unique(table(a))==1 && length(unique(table(a)))==1){
    return(a)
  }
  else{
    for (i in a){
      if (table(a)[[i]]>=2){
        CAPS.sum<-CAPS[1:as.vector(table(a)[[i]])-1]
        val<-c(i,paste0(i,CAPS.sum))
        del<-a[!a %in% i]
        vec<-append(del,val,after=i-1)
        return(vec)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have used the following vectors of day numbers for testing and they highlight every possible outcome known so far.

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8)
c<-c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6)
d<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
e<-c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7)
f<-c(2,7,8,10,11,11,14)
```

It produces the following output:-

```
> DAYREP(a)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> DAYREP(b)
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "8A"
> DAYREP(c)
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "3A" "4"  "5"  "6" 
> DAYREP(d)
[1] "1"  "1A" "1B" "1C" "1D" "1E"
> DAYREP(e)
[1] "1"  "2"  "2A" "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "6"  "7" 
> DAYREP(f)
Error in table(a)[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

The function works on all the tests but e and f. With e it only converts the first set of repeated values, and with f it returns an error message.

I am aware that the problem is being caused by the `table(a)[[i]]` element calling the frequency value from the table, however I am unsure as to whether or not there is a method to call the values being tabulated from the table. E.g.

```
> table(e)
e
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
1 2 1 1 1 2 1
```

The method I am using is calling the bottom line, however I wish to call the top line. Does anybody know of a solution to this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `make.unique` function?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with it before, but I've just looked it up and it does what I wanted the above code to do. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `LETTERS` rather than typing in all of them by hand.

Comment: Ben, if @cr1msonB1ade answered your question with the comment, feel free to write it up and answer your own question. Just give him credit when you write it.

Answer (score 0):

@cr1msonB1ade has kindly suggested the use of the `make.unique` function which is able to perform what the above function does with slight variation.

```
> make.unique(e)
[1] "1"   "2"   "2.1" "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "6.1" "7"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment I think what you want is the builtin function `make.unique`, but there are also some issues with how you are using the table, so I would like to address those as well. When you want to access the values in a `table` via the name of the variable (`i` in your for loop), you want to index with single brackets `[` not double brackets `[[`. The other issue is that table converts the values to factors and thus you would have to index with an `as.character(i)`. I don't think this completely fixed your script, but it might get you close enough.